# Georeferencing PNG from bounding box in GDAL?

Tags: gdal, georeferencing, png

I have an image in PNG format and bounding box coordinates (upper left, lower right). How do I georeference it using command-line interface tools such as GDAL (or Python if it is not possible)?

In the end, I want to open the PNG image in QGIS but NOT use QGIS to georeference it (because I need to create an automation script).

for instance, the image name is `image.png` and the bounding box is `53.1111876266,11.7303748998,55.5611387985,13.1036943879`. What should I type in my terminal?

Comment: Possibly `gdal_translate -co "WORLDFILE=YES" image.png output.png`  you might also need to use  -a_ullr <ulx> <uly> <lrx> <lry>

Comment: @nmtoken thanks this gives enough clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdal_translate` is the tool. the command below will take the image.png, assign/georeference based on the bounding box (upper left, lower right) coordinates, and create an `.aux.xml` which containes the georeferencing location. Use the `-a_ullr` attributes. Further, [read the documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html).

`C:/> gdal_translate image.png output_georeferenced.png -a_ullr 53.1111876266 11.7303748998 55.5611387985 13.1036943879 -a_srs EPSG:4326`